# Scribus Jpegs not appearing on first insertion

Tags: scribus

Hi I'm new to Scribus but have been working through my first document well. However this evening have hit a problem...

I  can insert an image frame, select a jpeg image and frequently it's just not appearing.

Some images are appearing but then some will not. There seems to be no reason why some work and some don't.

Then preview mode a number of Jpegs which were looking perfect suddenly disappear.

These are files which have been scanned and saved as Jpegs. Actual photograph Jpegs are inserting fine.

Has anyone any ideas about what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks very much!

---

Thanks so much for the reply @a.l.e
I've checked the image scaling but that isn't the problem.

The printer company I'm going to use scanned in all of the images I'm having a probem with.

One was a photo. It's gone in fine. (Exported to PDF no issues. I checked).
That was 3.31mb
Width 3518, Height 5210
Horizontal Resolution 72dpi
Vertical Resolution 72 dpi 
Bit Depth 24

One was a Newpaper article 12.7mb
Width 5940, Height 8652
Horzontal Resolution 72dpi
Vertical Resolution 72 dpi
Bit Depth 24

Many were scanned handdrawn A4 pages ranging from 2.37 - to over 6mb
They were all around Width 4852 Height 7020
Horizontal and Vertical resolutions are blank
Bit Depth 24

Do you have ideas please?

(Edit) Just been doing some more work. Most of the images are appearing on screen now. There are about 6 missing (now with a big red X on most of them). However, when I try and export this draft to PDF, the very first previously questionable image comes up as missing and so the export stops then!

Comment: First of all, I've never used Scribus... buuut the red x sounds like the image is linked to the Scribus document and now it's missing. Like let's say you got images on a thumb drive, you place them in Scribus and then remove the thumb drive, Scribus would not be able to find the images anymore. Another possible situation where the image can't be located could be renaming the file or moving it. I'm not a 100% sure, but quick googling seems to say you can manage linked images from `Extras > Manage Images `.

Comment: i've edited my reply above with a few more hint related to the path to the images.

Comment: The files are definitely in the right place. When I use the manage images tool and Scribus is looking in the correct folder no files are showing in the folder at all!! How can this be when I've checked a full folder literally seconds before? It's only a problem with these scanned jpeg images. I tried gimp to change one from a .jpeg to a .tif but when I select that as an image to put into scribus, it crashes Scribus! I'm tearing my hair out and running out of time so any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: It kinda sounds like there might be a file permission issue or something... I don't know how that could happen though. — What if you try to copy the images into a subfolder next to your Scribus project file and use the `Search` button in the `Manage Images` window to relink the images. You may have already done this, but I'm kinda out of ideas.

Comment: the issue could be with the images and not Scribus. If this is the case, converting them as you did should help. Did you try other file formats (png)? Otherwise, could you send us a copy?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you only see the top left corner?

When the image as at high resolution and if you have not told Scribus to automatically scale your images, you will only see one small part of the image. Typically, the top left corner.

To check if this is your issue, select the image frame, open the Properties Palette ("Window > Properties"), click on the "Image" tab and then activate "Scale to frame size".

If this does not bring you further, my next guess would be that the scanner is saving the images in a format that Scribus does not support (and is probably not Jpeg; there are a lot of "esoteric" version of Jpeg and not all of them are supported by Scribus: that is also possible).

If you're sure that the image is "normal" Jpeg, I fear that I would need a sample image to help you further.

After you reply and @Joonas comment, there is a second possible why you don't see the images.

You might have move the images, renamed them, renamed a directory in the path leading to the image or ejected the external drive where they are.

By default, Scribus is only linking to the images (for very good reasons!) and you have to make sure that it can find them at the very moment when you open the Scribus file.
If you see a red X this a huge hint that the address of the image is not (anymore) correct.
(One more option: the directory contains "invalid" characters, but this nowadays rather unlikely, since almost every character should now be valid...)

As Jonas wrote in a comment below, "Extra > Manage Images" is a good tool in Scribus to check the paths to the images.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I've checked the scaling and that isn't the problem.

Comment: This is a very helpful summary of steps to try or consider, when hitting "no photo" problems in Scribus.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Save a copy of your document, and open the copy. This worked for me, but I still have no clear idea why.

Hi there, I've had the exact same issue in 2023 with version 1.4.8. Not only were images not loading at all in photo frames, but some of the photos began to disappear in the document as I added more and more content.

After attempting all of the suggestions in this thread, nothing worked. File directories correct etc.

My final hypothesis was simply that the file was so large and bloated with content, that Scribus was struggling to load all of the numerous directories at once, that perhaps by splitting the document into two more manageable halves, it would work correctly.

So I saved two separate copies of the original document, one titled 'first half' and one titled 'second half', with the intention of removing the second half of the pages from the first document, and the first half of the pages from the second document.

However, when I opened the first duplicate of the file, all of my images were there, and I could successfully add new images! I hope this can help someone who is having this issue.